# Setting up an alert for certain key sequences

Tags: macos, google-chrome, security, passwords, google-chrome-extensions

I'm trying to fight my password reuse. When setting up new accounts for various online services, I always generate and store their passwords in the manager, however I still got dozens of old accounts which use about 3 different passwords (I know, right).

They aren't stored anywhere so I can't run an analysis tool. I can't remember all the websites which got these passwords (only through haveivebeenpwned, haha). When I log in with these passwords I almost always forget to change it.

So I had an idea — what if the OS or the browser would alert me when I enter any of those bad passwords on any page and remind me to actually change the password. How can I do this on macOS with Chrome? Perhaps with some kind of an Automator script or a Chrome extension?

Comment: Shouldn't you just generate a new password any time you log into an account by hand (rather than letting the password manager auto-fill it)?  Alternately, some password managers will prompt you to save login info when they see you log into a site, after which you will have the passwords stored and can check for duplicates.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov Exactly, I really should generate a new password any time I log into a bad-passworded account. The thing is, I forget, and thus the question how to remind me about this.